# What's the difference between a target and a reference (reStructuredText)?

Tags: hyperlink, anchor, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

What's the difference between a `target` and a `reference` in reStructured Text?

I'm trying to understand the reST spec and how hyperlinks work in sphinx, which is surprisingly non-intuitive.

Unfortunately, the documentation just says "to be completed" for the `target` and `reference` elements:

- https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/doctree.html#target
- https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/doctree.html#reference

What's the difference between `target` and `reference` elements in `.rst` files.

(Bonus: why isn't the above documentation complete? Are these elements new to reStructuredText?)

Comment: `target` and `reference` are not keywords that occur in RST files. They are XML elements in the Docutils data structure (the "document tree").

Comment: See https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#hyperlink-targets and https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#hyperlink-references. In basic terms, a target is where the browser ends up after clicking a reference link.